# How to calculate number of wins, frequency played and winning percentage

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I previously created a program for users to play my `NumBaseBall` Game. I would like to add three more functionalities to it:

(1) Display the number of wins,
(2) Display the frequency played
(3) Display the player's winning %

I have an external class called `GameResults` that contains a method for calculating strikes or balls that determines the outcome of the game and another that checks to see if the player wants to play again.
How can I achieve these additional three functionalities without having my cumulative data for each erased each time a new instance of `GameResults` is created if the user decides to play again? 
Here is my working code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
           PlayBall();
        }
        while (GameResults.PlayAgain());
    }

    public static void PlayBall()
    {       
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t*************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t*          Let's Have Fun           *");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t*           Welcome To The          *");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t*       Number Baseball Game        *");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t*************************************\n");

        GameResults gameresults =  new GameResults(); 

            for (int trysCounter = 1; trysCounter <= 5; trysCounter++)
            {
                gameresults.Strikes = 0;

                Random r = new Random();
                var myRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 9);
                var computerNumbers = myRange.OrderBy(i => r.Next()).Take(3).ToList();
                Console.WriteLine("The Game's Three Random Integers Are: (Hidden from user)");
                foreach (int integer in computerNumbers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", integer);
                }

                List<int> playerNumbers = new List<int>();
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Three Unique Single Digit Integers and Press ENTER after each:");
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("");
                    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    playerNumbers.Add(number);
                }

                gameresults.StrikesOrBalls(computerNumbers, playerNumbers);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------> Computer's Numbers = {0}{1}{2}", computerNumbers[0], computerNumbers[1], computerNumbers[2]);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------> Player's Numbers = {0}{1}{2}", playerNumbers[0], playerNumbers[1], playerNumbers[2]);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------> Game Results = {0} STRIKES & {1} BALLS\n", gameresults.Strikes, gameresults.Balls);
                Console.WriteLine("You have tried {0} times\n", trysCounter);

                gameresults.TotalStrikes = gameresults.TotalStrikes + gameresults.Strikes;

                Console.WriteLine("STRIKES = {0} ", gameresults.TotalStrikes);

                if (gameresults.TotalStrikes >= 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------> YOU ARE A WINNER!!!");
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (gameresults.TotalStrikes < 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YOU LOSE :(");
            } 
    }

}
```

Here are my external methods:

```
public void StrikesOrBalls(List<int> computer, List<int> player)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++)
            {
                if (computer[c] == player[p] && computer[c] != player[c])
                    Balls++;
            }
        }

        if(computer[0]== player[0])
            Strikes++;
        if(computer[1] == player[1])
            Strikes++;
        if(computer[2] == player[2])
            Strikes++;
    }

    public static bool PlayAgain()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Do you want to play again [YES/NO]?\n");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (answer == "YES")
                return true;
            if (answer == "NO")
                Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing NumBaseBall :) Goodbye!");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are a few ways to skin this.  You can create a separate cumulative object and declare it at the class level, or in your Main() method and pass it into PlayBall().  You can move your GameResults object out of PlayBall() and have a way to clear the stats for the current game but keep a running total across games, and just pass it into PlayBall() for each iteration.

Comment: *"How can I achieve these additional three functionalities without having my cumulative data for each erased each time a new instance of GameResults is created if the user decides to play again"* Then don't create a new `GameResults` each time the user starts a new game, or add it to a `List<GameResults>` and save it somewhere.

Comment: @dustmouse can you expand on the first option i think the second  will require too much changes to my code beyond my knowledge

Comment: You would create a class called CumulativeResults or something, and then add the three additional criteria to it.  You can instantiate it in your Main() method and pass it in to PlayBall().  For the first criteria, you can call a method on cumulativeResults in your `if (gameresults.TotalStrikes >= 3)` block to increment a counter for the number of wins.

Comment: @dustmouse Hey thanks a million it works, would you mind voting up my question if you think it was a good one? thanks!

Comment: @AaronLWG: I have seen people asking to upvote the answer. You are a first who is asking to upvote a question. :D

Comment: thanks for the upvote though! lol @displayName